# OneSignal overrided notification of firebase notification iOS Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

In my case:

- I have an old version of the app using OneSignal (and I subscribed to a tag "tag1") => For the new version I want to use Firebase FCM (and I subscribed to the topic "tag1") to push notifications in my app.
- For my back-end, I need to keep both OneSignal push API and Firebase FCM API to keep the old app version still having a push.
- But, I get duplicate a push.
  => I decided to initiate OneSignal SDK again to unsubscribe the old topic in the old app. And I have only push.
  It works perfectly for the Android platform, but for iOS I think OneSignal SDK overrides my Firebase FCM platform, **Firebase FCM does not have the event on .listen function**.
- I tried init, unsubscribing old the tags of OneSignal SDK before working with Firebase FCM.